# CSV Detector in Apache Tika

Tags: java, csv, apache-tika

I'm using the Java library **Tika** by Apache (`tika-core` ver. `1.10`).

Exists a `org.apache.tika.detect.Detector` for CSV files?
The MIME type should be `text/csv`, but I cannot find anything like that.

I would like to use the nice `detect` method

Comment: The main `MimeTypes` detector should cover you for that. What happens if you just try with `DefaultDetetor` or `TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig().getDetector()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently (v1.10) `tika-mimetypes.xml` defines `text/csv` like this:

```
<mime-type type="text/csv">
  <glob pattern="*.csv"/>
  <sub-class-of type="text/plain"/>
</mime-type>
```

This means that Apache Tika detects only by filename. If you use `Tika#detect(File)` Tika will add filename (under `Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY` key) to `Metadata` object passed to detector. There's similar behavior for URLs.

If you want to inject filename you can use something like:

```
new Tika().detect(is, fileName)
```

If you want some heuristics, based on content, feel free to check and file a ticket in [Tika's JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA).